trigger insert query
iam making trigger insert query
CREATE TRIGGER  trg_insertZYP_NEW
ON  ZYP 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ZYP (zy_id)  
VALUES (NEW.zy_id);
END ;

showing error the object 'ZYP' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.
I am try this query on sql database

The trigger is set to execute AFTER INSERT on the table ZYP. When an INSERT operation occurs on ZYP, this trigger fires and tries to insert another row into ZYP.
This will create an infinite loop of trigger executions because each INSERT triggers the trigger again, resulting in an endless chain of inserts.
CREATE TRIGGER trg_insertZYP_NEW 
ON ZYP 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ZYP_Log (zy_id)
    SELECT zy_id FROM inserted;
END;

This syntax is in sql server but you can modify as per your sql platform
